# 3 subplot x axis with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

Is there anyway to create an x axis with 3 subplots using facet_wrap? Below is some of my data:

```
structure(list(E2F4 = c("+/+", "+/+", "+/+", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", 
"-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "+/+", "+/+", "+/+", 
"+/+", "+/+", "+/+", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "-/-", 
"-/-", "-/-", "-/-", "+/+", "+/+", "+/+"), Colonies = c(1052, 
983, 1057, 497, 464, 437, 111, 81, 85, 40, 42, 43, 523, 523, 
636, 646, 730, 749, 58, 60, 53, 705, 746, 785, 54, 82, 80, 1618, 
1470, 1505), Clone = c("HT29", "HT29", "HT29", "7", "7", "7", 
"11", "11", "11", "2", "2", "2", "Control", "Control", "Control", 
"Control", "Control", "Control", "2", "2", "2", "7", "7", "7", 
"11", "11", "11", "HT29", "HT29", "HT29"), Well = c("32", "32", 
"32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", 
"32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32", 
"32", "32", "32", "32", "32", "32"), Hour = c(24, 24, 24, 24, 
24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 
48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48)), row.names = c(NA, -30L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Right now my graph has two subplots, but I need to add another for my "Hour" column. Does anyone know how I can do that? Graph photo attached.

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG9UB.png)

Here's a bit of the relevant code:

```
ggplot(welldata, aes(x = E2F4, y = Colonies, color = Clone, fill 
= E2F4)) +
geom_point(aes(color = Clone), size = 2) +
  geom_errorbar(data = datX, mapping = aes(x = E2F4, ymin 
=Colonies - Errors, ymax = Colonies + Errors)

facet_wrap(~Well, nrow = 1, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(strip.placement = "outside", panel.spacing = unit(0, 
  "cm"),  
    strip.text = element_text(size = 10, margin = margin(b=15)),  
    legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
    plot.title = element_text(margin = margin(b=10)))
```

Datx:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(x = "-/-", y = 2837.3333, Well = "0", errors = 334.02993877795)
dat2 <- data.frame(x = "+/+", y = 1911.33333, Well = "0", errors = 103.568010)
dat3 <- data.frame(x = "-/-", y = 137, Well = "8", errors = 158.745)
dat4 <- data.frame(x = "+/+", y = 259.6667, Well = "8", errors = 197.616630)
dat5 <- data.frame(x = "-/-", y = 95.666, Well = "16", errors = 93.0931)
dat6 <- data.frame(x = "+/+", y = 557.6667, Well = "16", errors = 133.82949)
dat7 <- data.frame(x = "-/-", y = 74.333, Well = "32", errors = 66.515)
dat8 <- data.frame(x = "+/+", y = 757.3333, Well = "32", errors = 43.98106)

datX <- bind_rows(dat1, dat2, dat3, dat4, dat5, dat6, dat7, dat8)
colnames(datX) <- c('E2F4','Colonies','Well','Errors')

datX %>% mutate(ymin = Colonies - Errors, ymax = Colonies + Errors) %>%
mutate(Well = factor(Well, levels = levels(well_data4$Well)))
```

Comment: Could we get info about `datX`?

Comment: Yes sorry just added!

Comment: Your code appears incomplete, `facet_wrap(..` starts before `geom_errorbar(..` is closed out.

Comment: Oh yea sorry I have some things in between that I didn't think was necessary to put in so I just broke it up -- they are just coloring and filling stuff. Do you need the entire thing?